# Suddenly everything got black and themes error

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gnome-terminal, gtk3

Hello everyone i am using ubuntu from 4 months and haven't faced any problem like that. Today when i am using my ubuntu i don't know what happened suddenly my terminal became something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ONwn.png
and every text in my desktop got messed up and when i tried to update then it shows theme parsing error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGQko.png